# Apache 2.4 VirtualHost ServerName is ignored

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, virtualhost, httpd.conf

On Amazon EC2, I have the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName   a.example.com
    ServerRoot   /var/www/a.example.com
    DocumentRoot html
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName   b.example.com
    ServerRoot   /var/www/b.example.com
    DocumentRoot html
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName   c.example.com
    ServerRoot   /var/www/c.example.com
    DocumentRoot html
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is, that despite the above configuration being correct, all requests to any of the 3 domain names are being directed as if the request went to `c.example.com` - as if the `ServerName` values are just being ignored.

Anyone see a problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ServerRoot`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serverroot) is allowed only in [server config Context](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directive-dict.html#Context), not in `VirtualHost`

> If you try to use it elsewhere, you'll get a configuration error that
>   will either **prevent the server from handling requests in that
>   context correctly**, or will keep the server from operating at all --
>   i.e., the server won't even start.

Comment: Amazing. No warnings, no errors, file has no parsing errors, even `httpd -S` displays correct VirtualHost routing... just amazingly bad error reporting.

Comment: It indeed is a bit strange. In fact, the directive seems to work fine even in `VirtualHost`, except that only the last one is applied (there is even no sense in having multiple `ServerRoot` directives since it determines the location of many other relative paths)

Answer (score 0):

The problem I found, is that my build of Apache2:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Amazon)
Server built:   Mar  7 2016 22:32:11
```

Is not handling the `DocumentRoot` parameter properly.

At the DocumentRoot config definition [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot), it says

> If the directory-path is not absolute then it is assumed to be
>   relative to the ServerRoot.

Well, this is apparently being ignored, because if I change the `DocumentRoot` value as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName   b.example.com
    ServerRoot   /var/www/b.example.com
    DocumentRoot html
</VirtualHost>
```

To this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName   b.example.com
    ServerRoot   /var/www/b.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/b.example.com/html   #<-- updated
</VirtualHost>
```

Then the configuration works. I haven't tested to see if this is an issue with the core Apache build, or if it's with the Amazon version, either way, I hope this answer helps someone.